# Minimalistic build setup for Vuejs without Webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, http-vue-loader

I'm using http-vue-loader for loading Vue single file components in my project. The main reason is to skip Webpack and fully concetrate on ES6 and Vue. Unfortunatelly I cannot use import in SF components. It is limitation of http-vue-loader(see the open [issues](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader/issues/84) on github)

Are there any other alternatives(fully ES6)? Or do I need to move to Webpack?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org) to scaffold your project. It fully manages Webpack (among other things) configuration for you so you can enjoy all of the features of Webpack (SFC, CSS loader, integration with SCSS/Less, hot reloading in dev env, minification and tree shaking in production build and many more) without the need to write single file of Webpack configuration

Comment: Of course I know about CLI. But still I'm not comfortable about the magic behind. Is it possible to use only ES6 with it's modules(I mean to disable Babel at least)